# rewrite part of url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a url like this:
`http://localhost/mysite/application/assets/projects/projectname`

I want this:
`http://localhost/mysite/projectname`.
I'm using this code in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^applicaion/assets/projects/(.*)$ http://localhost/mysite/$1 [QSA,L]
```

but when I hit `http://localhost/mysite/projectname` , apache error : `object not found`. 
what's wrong ?

project: https://docs.google.com/file/d/1TsNsxSMqBZOkdRKWMZ606dKVSz0_k2coBJ4qmmByl2ksWYG2D1J2nog_97bT/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solve my case:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application/assets/projects/$1/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application/assets/projects/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This will work - keep in mind you're making apache do a stat on the filesystem on pageload to check for existance...

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the rewrite rule has a ^ in the beginning which makes the rule require that the URI *begins* with application/assets/etc...

However, your original URL starts with mysite/application

Trying changing the rule to include mysite in it..

Comment: I have tried RewriteRule ^http://localhost/mysite/applicaion/assets/projects/(.*)$ http://localhost/mysite/$1 [QSA,L] . Not working

Comment: attachment : https://docs.google.com/file/d/1TsNsxSMqBZOkdRKWMZ606dKVSz0_k2coBJ4qmmByl2ksWYG2D1J2nog_97bT/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You'll want something like ^(mysite/applicaion/assets/projects/)(.*) to /mysite/$2  (I'm taking a stab at it but don't have the ability to test it at the moment)